# Constructing a HTML View in GWT (Google App Engine) with Google Maps V2, Facebook Comments, etc - layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-app-engine, gwt

Hi Im new to GWT and Google App Engine. Im trying to layout which looks like the image. However, Im not sure whats the best way to achieve this.

[image]

There are several ways according to GWT documentation such as: UIBinder, Layout Panels (Im using this approach in the image).... etc.

However, my UI is not that complicated. I have a div with the navigation bar on top, a div with a map(Javascript, a div with Facebook comments(javascript), and a div with some functionality which I wrote for ratings etc.

Thus mostly this webpage invokes a lot of javascript and third party stuff.

Here is some code that accomplishes this

```
        String header = "<div><h3>Navigation bar here</h3></div>";
    String east = "<div><h3>Rating System here</h3></div>";
    String south = "<div><h3>Facebook comments here</h3></div>";


    dock.addNorth(new HTML(header), 75);

    dock.addSouth(new HTML(south),50);
    dock.addEast(new HTML(east), 300);
    dock.add(map);

    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(dock);
```

I tried entering some Javascript in that html string to be added to the map. However, it didnt show up on the view. Seems like the html only works if its text, is that caorrect?

Whats the best way to construct this in GWT?

Could someone please point me to some examples of code/ tutorials?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a website like you project to do (link in my profile).

There is a jar file available for mapping maps v3 in gwt.

Here it is : http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/downloads/detail?name=gwt-maps-3.8.0-pre1.zip

Take care of GAE ... if your application must stay in "free", and you plan to make it available for others users, you will ran out of quota pretty fast :-(

(I gets 60% of instance time with only googlebots ...)

Anyway, just make an almost empty html, and build your panels from scratch.